# Why doesn't md5 match Perl's Digest::MD5 output?

Tags: perl, md5, ksh

Running the md5 function from the ksh terminal does not matching the output from a simple Perl script.

In the terminal I run:

```
echo -n abc | md5
62fecf21103616856d72e6ffc9bcb06b
```

If I run it using Perl:

```
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex);

foreach (@ARGV) {
   print "Digest is ", md5_hex($_), "\n";
}
exit
```

I get

```
./perl_test.sh abc
Digest is 900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72
```

In all the samples I see and the sample of the `md5` function itself the Perl one looks right but the one using just Ksh doesn't:

```
md5 -x
MD5 test suite:
MD5 ("") = d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
MD5 ("a") = 0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661
MD5 ("abc") = 900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72
```

Comment: Is `echo` outputting the space between the 'c' and the pipe?

Comment: md5 is not a ksh function. BTW, this will also give results that match your Perl version: `echo -e 'abc\c' | md5`. @Anon.: No, try `echo abc |hd` (or `hexdump -C`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the more portable `printf`

```
printf "abc" | md5
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Don't know why I didn't post the question here earlier.

Comment: After seeing these responses and thanks to @ghostdog74 and Dennis Wiliamson I ended up going with

    echo "abc/c" | md5

I reckon I read that man page 15 times but never noticed the bit about /c.

Answer (score 4):

Your `echo` doesn't recognize the -n option, so you are hashing the string '-n abc\n'.

Comment: I have tried with only

    echo abc | md5

but still get the incorrect hash.

How do I remove the linefeed or do you know of another way of creating md5 hashes quickly using ksh?
    0bee89b07a248e27c83fc3d5951213c1

Comment: @Anthony: try `/bin/echo -n abc | md5` or maybe /usr/bin/echo

Answer (score 1):

Further to [GregS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270131/ksh-md5-function-not-matching-perl-md5-output/2270169#2270169)'s answer, some examples:

```
$ md5 -s "-n abc"$'\012' # \012 = newline
MD5 ("-n abc
") = 62fecf21103616856d72e6ffc9bcb06b
```

And

```
$ md5 -s "abc"
MD5 ("abc") = 900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72
```

Answer (score 0):

When I run into these issues, I normally do something like this to check what my output is (for example showing tabs, versus spaces and so forth)

```
$ echo abc | hexdump -c
0000000   a   b   c  \n                                                
0000004
```